# Hyperledger Fabric Metric for peer communication with individual peers

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm trying to use Hyperledger Fabric to track communication with individual peers. Assuming that our peer is connected to 3 other peers, I'd like to track metrics for each individual connection to those peers.

I see there is a metric for gossip.comm.messages_sent, but I assume it only counts the total number of messages to all peers. Is there a way to get message counts for the connection to individual peers? I.e. a per-peer communication metric? Or any other way to track the communication between individual peers?